# NSInvalidArgumentException desired type = NSString; given type = __NSDictionaryM; Unacceptable type of value : property

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnull

Here i am setting some values using the `NSManagedObject`.

First problem i got that when i am trying to assign the null value to the property it is giving error :

`desired type = NSString;`

given type =null.

I am getting values from `NSDictionary` serialized from a JSON file. But when the value is null i get the crash giving above error:

`desired type = NSString;`

given type =null.

For this i am writing the the following code but still i get the error.What should i do to handle null value correctly.

```
    NSManagedObject *updateDevice=[results lastObject];

           if([results count] > 0){
                        //if(1){
              NSLog(@"updateeeee");
                        //continue;
   [updateDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"clip_image_path"]] forKey:@"clip_image_path"];
   [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"] forKey:@"clip_name"];
   [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"page_categorisation"] forKey:@"page_categorisation"];
```

following properties have the null values

```
  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict    forKey:@"personality_company_master_values"];

  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"category_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil: dict forKey:@"category_master_values"];

  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"brand_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict forKey:@"brand_master_values"];

  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"company_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict forKey:@"company_master_values"];

  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"product_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict forKey:@"product_master_values"];

  [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"industry_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict forKey:@"industry_master_values"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error cited in your question title because this line:

```
[updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict    forKey:@"personality_company_master_values"];
```

is passing `dict` to the `setValue:` if the condition fails.  Try replacing with:

```
[updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil: [dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] forKey:@"personality_company_master_values"];
```

ie. pass the relevant element of the dictionary, not the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code. First of all it is better to use `isEqual:` method rather then `==` to compare with `NSNull`:

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]
```

One more issue is how you are using `?:` operator. If set brackets it will looks like:

```
[updateDevice setValue:([dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] == [NSNull null] ? nil:dict) forKey:@"personality_company_master_values"];
```

Are you sure `dict` isn't `nil`? Or maybe you've missed `]`?

Comment: I have set the brackets but it giving me the same error. setting up values here   [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"] forKey:@"clip_name"];  this is correct but for null values i am not getting hoe to check for it. suggest me other way to check for null value. @Mikhail

Comment: @vicky check my answer

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code before set the value

```
 if ([updateDevice valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] && ![[updateDevice valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
 [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]    forKey:@"personality_company_master_values"];
```

Comment: no it is not setting proper value for  personality_company_master_values it is giving null but it has some value for some clips @balkaran singh

Comment: it check's  personality_company_master_values has value and personality_company_master_values is not null class. if personality_company_master_values have value it set the value.

Comment: then why it's not setting the value i am using the code you have suggested. @balkaran Singh

Comment: check your db  personality_company_master_values have any value or not. you can usr nslog("%@",[updateDevice valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]);

Comment: I can't say about that...i am in trouble here... but it's not working, anyway thanks for the help dude @balkaran Singh